# How can i code my java code to make PHP exec command store answer?

Tags: java, php, exec

Ok, I have some java code :

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    if(args.length == 2){
        try {
        System.out.print(DecryptHash(args[0],args[1]));
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else if(args.length == 3){
        try {
            System.out.print(GenerateHash(args[0], args[1], args[2]));
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    else
        System.out.println("Wrong command");

}
```

I want to use this class with php. So I use de command exec like that,

```
exec("java -jar VerifyHash \"$Key\" \"$SignedHash\"",$DecryptedHash);
print_r(array_values($DecryptedHash));
```

but here is the result : Array ( )

So i decided to see if it was the command I pass to the exec() that was wrong, so I echoed it and passed the command manualy in a command shell, it worked.

My jar is in the same directory as my .php, what am I doing wrong? Is it the war I return the value that is not correct(System.out.print), is it because I am supposed to specify a complete path to the .jar?

Comment: Is the java command in PHP's search path? what does exec ('echo $PATH' ) produce? You could try specifying the full path to java as well.

Comment: Nice idea, didn't work, I specified the who path and I still get nothing from my Array

Comment: You could try redirecting the error stream to standard out: append `2>&1` to the end of the command. Making sure PHP has permission to read the jar file is another thing you could try.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it helps but it should be:

```
exec("java -jar VerifyHash.jar \"$Key\" \"$SignedHash\"",$DecryptedHash);
```

where VerifyHash.jar is your compiled java program.

Comment: oh, I didn't copied the good version of the code I already made this modification but didn't solve the problem. Sry my bad there.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried print_r without the array_values
Also wrapping your array?

Comment: Just print_r($DecryptedHash);

Comment: It is easier to find if you add information by editing your answer instead of adding a comment.

Comment: Sorry not easy typing on an iPhone. Was it really that difficult to understand what I was suggesting?

Comment: Not at all, your answer is fine. I simply suggest that you add _"Just print_r($DecryptedHash);"_ to the answer instead of creating a comment. It is easier to find the relevant information like that.

Comment: Ah okay thanks elusive. I'm still new, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: didn't help, same result it just gives me Array().

Comment: sorry im stuck for ideas. is it possible your application is throwing an exception?  e.printStackTrace(); may not get reported to standard out, which means your array will come back empty.  can you try something like exec("java -version",$output); and see what comes back as a test?

Comment: Found the problem... I compiled the .JAR in java 7 and the server had java6 installed on it...

I should drink more coffee :S

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem... I compiled the .JAR in java 7 and the server had java6 installed on it...

I should drink more coffee :S